# Inverse Laplace transform of a Gaussian Bell curve

Tags: laplace-transform

Is it possible to find a continuous bounded real function $f$ such that $\mathcal Lf(z)=\exp(-z^2)$ where $\mathcal Lf(z)=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-tz}f(t)dt$ ?

I don't find anything in the tables...

Comment: Interesting indeed. How did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Is moment generating function (MGF)  of a Gaussian of any help?

Comment: It's linked to this problem : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508702/question-about-the-sequence-of-moments-of-a-continuous-function

Comment: If we put $t=e^{-x}$ in $M_n(f)=\int_0^1 f(t)\, t^n\, dt$, then $M_n(f)=\int_0^{+\infty} f(e^{-x})e^{-(n+1)x}dx$ is a Laplace transform of the function $g$ defined by $g(x)=f(e^{-x})$. So if it is possible to find $g$ verifying $\mathcal Lg(z)=\exp(−z^2)$ we should be able to find $f$ with $M_n(f)=\exp(-\lambda n^2)$...